# Joomla 'Category Blog' Menu Item Issues

Tags: menu-item

I'm having a bit of a problem with one of our sites.

I have a home page on my site which is a 'Category Blog' menu item. The page shows the latest article from the blog.

The problem is that when you click on the blog title or the 'read more' link, I would hope that you would be taken to the blog page and shown just this article.

Unfortunately however, the home page is displayed, along with all of the modules on the home page and the full article.

What I would like is that if you click on the article title or 'read more' link, you are taken to the single article.

Does this make sense? How can I do this?

Kind regards

James

Comment: Create a second blog layout menu item. Now that Itemid will be used for your detailpage.

Comment: Hi COBIZ,

That's what I have already and it isn't working.

Kind regards


James

Comment: Maybe (have never tried that) you could create a sub category within that category. Link the homepage to the parent and the second menu to the child.
Don't place articles in the parent, always use the subcategory.
Maybe that way you could control which itemid is used for the detail page.
But with a very big MAYBE...

Comment: Another solution could be, use Module Articles - Category on the homepage. Depending on your layout, this could solve your issue

Comment: Hi guys,

I've managed to solve it. It looks like it's only possible, at least I've only found this way to make it work...

You need to install a SEF component. I've used the sh404 Joomla component and it's now working as hoped.

Thanks for all of your contributions!

Kind regards


James

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Category View use Home Page Itemid when displaying the articles?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/why-does-category-view-use-home-page-itemid-when-displaying-the-articles)

Answer (score 1):

> Most likely you will find the answer here:
>   **[Why does Category View use Home Page Itemid when displaying the articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/why-does-category-view-use-home-page-itemid-when-displaying-the-articles)**

#### A brief outline

This is caused, because Joomla will use the "**wrong***" menu item id and will show your articles at the home page. In cases like these, there seems to be a "**mechanism**" that make the decision of what menu item id to use by certain precedence.

```
*wrong = not the one you wish it would use.
```

There is always the option to use a **SEF Component** to help you deal with this.

But you can also do some tricks with Joomla core and achieve what you want.

In this question here, the OP is encountering a similar if not the same issue. I have posted there an explanation and some tests you can do, to help you understand how things work. Make sure to read both the question and the answer:
**[Why does Category View use Home Page Itemid when displaying the articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/why-does-category-view-use-home-page-itemid-when-displaying-the-articles)**