# Why Item of a category is displayed in homepage, instead of its category menu item?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, k2, category

I am displaying several items in my homepage, which are grouped in a category. Let's say I have displayed several cars in my homepage, all of them are in the category 'Cars'.
I have a menu item called 'Cars' which is displaying all items inside this category.

Now the problem is when I click any item (car) it displays in my homepage, instead of displaying in my current menu 'Cars'.

I am using K2, and for my menu item Cars I have it to display `K2 » Latest items from (one or more) users or categories` where I selected Category 'Cars'.

Why is it displaying my items in my homepage when I click any Car Item?

Best regards.

Comment: Check this Q/A, maybe it will help: [Why does Category View use Home Page Itemid when displaying the articles?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/why-does-category-view-use-home-page-itemid-when-displaying-the-articles/8769#8769)

Comment: See if the answer of that question works for you. If yes, then this question should be considered a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Not a K2 expert, but that is not a "category menu item", it is a "latest items menu item". That is not good enough. As Lanah says in his answer you will have to create an actual category view menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with menu, create this secondary menu:

```
1. Cars - display k2 category.
    a. Car 1 - display k2 article
    b. Car 2 - display k2 article.
```

and on your homepage create `alias` for `1. Cars - display k2 category.`.

You end up with `example.com/cars/super-car-one` link to your single article.

regards.

Comment: I don't get it, so you mean I have to create a sub-menu for each item I have?

Comment: if you don't create sub menu for every item you will get link like: `example.com/cars/1-alias` that's all. I'm preferring aliases for all my static content, but if you got dynamic content ( articles are added often ) just create alias for category.