# How to link article to specific menu item?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, url, router

I have two menu items, for example **Menu1** and **Menu2**. Both are a **Category Blog** for same category **Cat1**, but **Menu1** has some specified **tags**.

Of course, some articles are present on both pages, and all `url`'s on both pages look like: `/Menu1/article1`.

How can I force Joomla! to link articles to second menu item? Or, maybe, how to make links without menu but with category name like: `/Cat1/article1`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your first menu item and remaking it? Sounds like you just want to prioritise the second category blog menu item and the router is finding the first one first.

Comment: Yes, I tried with no result.

Comment: It seems, order of menu items determines everything.

Answer (score 0):

This Q/A here (**[Why does Category View use Home Page Itemid when displaying the articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/why-does-category-view-use-home-page-itemid-when-displaying-the-articles)**) is rather similar and most likely it will answer your first question. How to force Joomla to use one menu item over the other for the same content item.

Although I don't know if the answer provided there is still valid, but it describes what was the case back then which is very likely it is still the same, or at least something similar.

Regarding making URLs without menu items, but based on categories, you can use a SEF extension like sh404SEF to achieve this. Although your content must be linked somehow in the front-end, for enabling sh404SEF to generate your URLs. So at least a few menu items will be needed anyway.